# How to add new json values(key value) to local variable?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am getting JSON data from local JSON file by using ajax jquery.

I have stored the JSON values in a variable.

I need to know how to add new json values(key, value) to the variable which I created for storing the values rather than to store the data in the local json file.

Please find the code below,

```
 var text = ["name", "email", "id"];
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var name = text[i];
    var toaddstr = 'S_name5'
    jsondata[name] = toaddstr; //Json variable(jsondata)
 }
 console.log(jsondata);
```

I am new to Jquery, please help me to find a solution

Comment: well, you haven't said what's wrong with the code? What does it produce? `jsondata` is not defined anywhere in your snippet. What does this object look like before your code runs? If I just define jsondata as an empty object, then your code above seems to work no problem: http://jsfiddle.net/724Lc08o/

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object from the JSON data that you received, E.g.

```
var dataObject = JSON.parse(jsondata);
```

(NOTE: please don't perform this operation inside the loop, do it before the loop)

Now you can add new key-value pairs to your object, E.g.

```
dataObject[name] = toaddstr;
```

Good luck.

Your modified code:

```
    var text = ["name", "email", "id"];
    var dataObject = JSON.parse(jsondata);
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var name = text[i];
        var toaddstr = 'S_name5'
        dataObject[name] = toaddstr; //object
    }
    console.log(dataObject);
```

P.S: It would help to see the json data that you receive